# Windows 10 - possible to change volume of a specific application without volume mixer or 3rd party software?

Tags: windows-10, audio, volume-mixer

I know it usually would be possible to set volume for specific applications simply by changing it through Windows volume mixer, just in some cases this doesnt work as expected.

Case 1: every time the application recieves an update, it will create a new subfolder, copy all required files there and by that be recognized as being a different application. Creating a short cut to the executable doesnt work as it seems Windows is storing volume mixer entries by specific executable files.

Case 2: volume mixer always resets the application to system default volume on each time the application is started and ignores the previous volume level - this might be a system bug or by design but is unwanted any way.
-> I tried deleting all related registry keys already, for all application running "normally", they have recreated their registry entries as expected, but the application which wont save doesnt create its own entry and I dont recognize the pattern in which the entries are stored.

Is there any way to change the volume of a specific application by command line, batch file, short cut command? I would like to avoid installing additional software to achieve this goal.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to this path in the registry editor:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\Audio\PolicyConfig\PropertyStore`

2. Find out which of those subkeys holds the volume level of your process. Afaik you need the PID of a process for that (Check the Details Tab of Task-Manager).
3. Convert the volume level you want to change the application to to a hexadecimal format. Use whatever you like for that. Online tools should suffice
4. Edit the registry key storing the volume level to your converted hexadecimal value

### *Going by your examples, I am pretty sure that what you really need is to reset the permissions on the parenting registry folders. The real answer in that case is:*

1. First create a restore point to have a backup of the status quo.
2. Take ownership of
   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\LowRegistry\Audio\PolicyConfig\PropertyStore` and all its sub-folders and delete it.
3. Should work right away. If not try running this in cmd (Administrator) and restarting your system:

```
dism.exe /online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
```

---

*IF i am right: You should be certain what really your question is before asking. No harm, no foul ;)*

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

There is one app called [EarTrumpet](https://ear-trumpet.software.informer.com/1.2/). I guess it can help you.

Comment: "Without volume mixer or 3rd party software?"